# Получить id итема в listview проведя пальцем

Tags: android

возможно ли как-нибудь получить айди итема в листвью проведя по нему пальцем?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095629/raw-coordinates-to-listview-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095629/raw-coordinates-to-listview-item)

Comment: а собственно как вы отлавливаете жест?